# The Proximal Operator of the $ {L}_{1} $ Norm of Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, proximal-operators

I hope to solve this problem.

$$\min \quad \left\| CX \right\|_{1} $$
$$ \text{s.t.}\quad AX=b, X >0 $$

where $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times m}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$. $C$ is known weight, $X$ is unknown matrix. My problem is how to calculate the proximal operator of $ \left\| CX \right\|_{1}$, I know, if without $C$ the proximal operator will be apply Shrinkage elementwise.

This problem will be easy if $x$ is a vector, we just need to solve a LP, but my $X$ is a matrix.

$$ \min \quad c^Tx $$ 
 $$ \text{s.t.}\quad Ax=b , x>0 $$

---

the overall problem I hope to solve is:
$$ \min \left\| CX \right\|_{1} + \lambda \left\| Y \right\|_{*} $$
$$ \text{s.t.}\quad AX+Y=b , X>0 $$
Y has the same dimension with $b \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$. X is known to be sparse.

Comment: Are you assuming that $C$ is diagonal?

Comment: If $C$ is diagonal you can indeed do a change of variables.

Comment: Since $C X$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, what do you mean by the $1$-norm of $CX$?  I suspect you don't mean the matrix norm induced by the vector $1$-norm.  Is $\| CX \|_1$ just the sum of the absolute values of the entries of $CX$?

Comment: Assuming that $\| CX \|_1$ is the sum of the absolute values of $CX$, and that $X \geq 0$ means each component of $X$ is nonnegative, your problem separates into $n$ independent subproblems, one for each column of $X$.  So there is no problem with $X$ being a matrix.

Comment: @littleO I mean $ \left\| CX \right\|_{1} $ is the sum of the absolute values of the enties of $CX$. I also need to minimize the nuclear norm of the Y, so I don't know whether I can separate it into n sub-problems.

Comment: OK, given that you do not mean the induced matrix norm, I've modified my answer.

Comment: I think I created a formulation to your *Overall Problem* which makes this sub problem much easier.

Answer (score 4):

The proximal operator for $\|CX\|_1$ does not admit an analytic solution. Therefore, to compute the proximal operator, you're going to have to solve a non-trivial convex optimization problem.

So why do that? Why not apply a more general convex optimization approach to the overall problem.

This problem is LP-representable, since 
$$\|CX\|_1 = \max_j \sum_i |(CX)_{ij}| = \max_j \sum_i \left| \sum_k C_{ik} X_{kj} \right|$$
So any linear programming system can solve this problem readily. Of course, having a modeling framework will help; for instance, in my package [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx), this is just:

```
cvx_begin
    variable X(m,n)
    minimize(max(sum(abs(C*X))))
    subject to
        A*X==B
        X >= 0
cvx_end
```

This assumes that $X>0$ is to be interpreted elementwise. You could also use `norm(C*X,1)` instead of `max(sum(abs(C*X)))` but in fact CVX will end up doing the same thing either way.

EDIT: From the comments, it looks like you want `sum(sum(abs(C*X)))` instead. Technically, $\|\cdot\|_1$ refers to the induced matrix norm, not the elementwise sum of the absolute values.

Comment: Thank you! The reason I hope to know the proximal operator of  $ \left\| CX \right\|_{1} $ is that, I hope to apply ADMM to solve my overall problem, I have edited my post, sorry for not list it at the first time.

Comment: Then my comment stands. In order to compute the proximal operator you're going to need to solve a convex optimization problem approximately as difficult as ADMM itself.

Comment: Sorry I don't know it is refers to the  induced matrix norm, does the proximal operator of `sum(sum(abs(C*X)))` have an analytic solution and how should I represent it in a right way. Would you please give me some advice on how to solve $ \min \left\| CX \right\|_{1} + \lambda  \left\| Y \right\|_{*} $. Another reason I am trying to apply ADMM is this problem have a big scale.

Comment: You're welcome to look at the paper I co-authored on TFOCS (Google should have no trouble finding it). One of the motivations for that work is precisely that forms like $\|CX\|_1$ (no matter how you define it) admit no simple prox function.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will read it.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, I think that for some cases of $ C $ one could have closed form solution. Certainly for the `sum(sum(abs(C*X)))` definition of the Norm. For example, if $ C $ is Diagonal. I think it also can be done for the case $ C $ is tight frame, right?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to do something regarding the overall problem you mentioned.

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{X, Y} \quad & {\left\| C X \right\|}_{1} + {\left\| Y \right\|}_{\ast} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & A X + Y = B \\
& {X}_{i, j} \geq 0, && \forall i, j
\end{aligned}$$

Now, let's define a function $ I \left( Z \right) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } {Z}_{i, j} \geq 0 \\ 
\infty & \text{ if } {Z}_{i, j} < 0
\end{cases} $ then we can rewrite the problem above as:

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{X, Y} \quad & {\left\| C X \right\|}_{1} + {\left\| Y \right\|}_{\ast} + I \left( Z \right) \\
\text{subject to} \quad & A X + Y = B \\
& X - Z = 0
\end{aligned}$$

Which is equivalent to:

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{X, Y} \quad & {\left\| C X \right\|}_{1} + {\left\| Y \right\|}_{\ast} + I \left( Z \right) \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \left( A - I \right) X + Y - Z - B = 0 \\
\end{aligned}$$

Now this is ADMM with 3 variables. It is known to have cases it doesn't converge but in practice form most cases it will.

In this case you have very efficient Proximal Operator for 2 of the 3 functions but even the proximal operator of $ {\left\| C X \right\|}_{1} $ can be solved pretty efficiently.
The reason is, that unlike your post above, you'll be solving something of the form:

$$ \arg \min_{X} {\left\| X - D \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \rho {\left\| C X \right\|}_{1} $$

Where $ D $ is a matrix of the composition of $ Z $, $ Y $ and $ B $.
To solve this Sub Problem you could do a change of variables:

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{X, W} \quad & {\left\| X - D \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \rho {\left\| W \right\|}_{1} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & C X - W = 0
\end{aligned}$$

Now, this is a classic ADMM (ADMM for the LASSO) which can be solved very efficiently.